# How run shell script from R or/and from Matlab?

Tags: shell, r, matlab

Let's assume that we have command `X` which can be executed in shell and return some result in stdout and stderr. Is it possible to do this from R or/and Matlab? And if yes, how can the result of command be handled?

Comment: Cygwin is not mentioned here, nor is the operating system - though that appears to be important given later comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use the system() command to execute shellscripts, system-commands, etc in R

it's documented at 
http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#System-and-foreign-language-interfaces

Comment: I haven't find infromation I want. Maybe I'm was not as attentive. But for example how can I execute simple "ls"(unix) or "dir"(win) command via R::system?

Comment: Actualy, I have tried to invoke system("ls") but it throws "write error: Bad file descriptor"

Comment: A <- system('ls', intern=TRUE );

Comment: this should assign the content of your working directory to the vecotr A

Comment: +1. Thank you @Nikolaus You are right. But I don't know why I can't run executables from my cygwin. I'm getting "/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/ls: write error: Bad file descriptor". Can you comment on this?

Comment: @Mihran: `/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/` is not a valid Windows file path.

Comment: I know @Joshua, but this is the result what pwd returns. And this works in cygwin.

Answer (score 5):

According to this [post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2010/05/17/calling-shell-commands-from-matlab/), you can call anything from any OS, using the system function. An Examples is `[status, result] = system(’dir’);`, to call the `dir` command on a UNIX-like OS.

From [MathWorks documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/system.html):

> `system('command')` calls upon the
>   operating system to run the specified
>   command, for example dir or ls or a
>   UNIX shell script, and directs the
>   output to the MATLAB software. The
>   command executes in a system shell,
>   which might not be the shell from
>   which you launched MATLAB. If command
>   runs successfully, ans is 0. If
>   command fails or does not exist on
>   your operating system, ans is a
>   nonzero value and an explanatory
>   message appears.
>
> `[status, result] = system('command')`
>   calls upon the operating system to run
>   command, and directs the output to
>   MATLAB. If command runs successfully,
>   status is 0 and result contains the
>   output from command. If command fails
>   or does not exist on your operating
>   system, status is a nonzero value and
>   result contains an explanatory
>   message.

See Michael Katz's blog [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2010/05/17/calling-shell-commands-from-matlab/)

Comment: Well, yes. Matlab and R are quite different. I don't really have experience with R. :)